# What do you call these cold pickled cucumber skewers in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, food

Is it correct or understood if I call these cold and pickled cucumber skewers "冰泡黄瓜"? [image]

Comment: That photo mainly comes up with JAPANESE restaurants or entrees though... https://www.ebarafoods.com/recipe/detail/recipe366.php

Answer (score 2):

冰鎮 =  chill with ice

pickled cucumber = 腌黄瓜

The item in the picture could be called 冰鎮腌黄瓜 or simply 冰鎮黄瓜

*Of course the seller can name it whatever he wants, for example '冰脆黄瓜串'*

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's a Japanese whole pickle.

So the Chinese name is :日式腌一整根黄瓜

See https://www.xiachufang.com/recipe/101868552/